# Simpler range finder?

Tags: php, range, if-statement

Hay guys

I've programmed a very simple range finder.

The user can only select numbers 1 - 180 (axis)

if the number is 90 or below i have to add 90 on to it
if the number is 91 - 180 i have to take off 90 from it.

Here's what i have

```
$min_range = range(1,90);
$max_range = range(91,180);

if(in_array($axis, $min_range)){
    $c = $axis + 90;
}elseif(in_array($axis, $max_range)){
    $c = $axis - 90;
}
```

Has anyone got a better solution

Comment: Could you give a range of user input values, and the corresponding output values you want/expect? Also, I'm curious as to why you're adding/subtracting the 90 at all.

Comment: if 65 is entered we need to add 90, if 140 is entered we need to subtract 90

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than store a huge array 1..90 and then test, why not just do an if based on less/greater than your data points?

```
if ($axis >= 1 && $axis <= 90) {
  $c = $axis + 90;
} else if ($axis > 90 && $axis <=180) {
  $c = $axis - 90;
} else {
  echo "Invalid input";
}
```